# Turn a page's javascript variable changes into a feed

Tags: javascript, rss

http://www.wtfcomics.com/index.html is the only website I follow that has neither RSS nor Twitter capabilities. I've tried services like page2RSS, and I've exhausted every last method of following a Facebook page that exists in this universe, and nothing works.

As a last resort, I looked at the page's source. The one thing that changes when he uploads a new comic is the javascript variable "newest_issues". I'm wondering if it's possible to create some kind of feed that will automatically notify me whenever that variable is changed from its current numbers, because RSS (or at least page2RSS) is incapable of doing that.

If this isn't possible, an alternative method is the Facebook page: I found the RSS feed for it, but that feed doesn't include wall posts by other people (even if I add &everyone to the end of the URL), which is a problem because the author currently posts to the page from his own Facebook account when he updates the site.

If THAT isn't possible, a final alternative method is a feed that watches the server for new image files, but I highly doubt it has folder permissions that will allow me to do that.

Comment: Not to nit-pick but I bet there are literally hundreds of millions of web sites without RSS or Twitter feeds.

Comment: That said, you could just write a `wget` or `curl` script to pull the site front page every few minutes and see if the checksum has changed.

Comment: I'm sure there are. I said the only one that I follow. Anyway, writing a script for it that my computer runs is a great, if much harder and more annoying, solution. I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: In fact it seems like it'd be a cool business idea, a site that polls whatever site you want and provides you with RSS/twitter/whatever :-)

Comment: Google search results: http://www.ghacks.net/2009/09/07/monitor-website-changes/ :-)

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Feed43 is amazing.

Comment: If it was my answer that was the one that helped you, please select it. (:

Answer (score 1):

I made a RSS feed with Feed43.com. Here it is, hope this is useful for you.
http://feed43.com/wtfcomics.xml